# assign a url output to a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

The below code works well. I am new to ajax.
Need is to assign the output of a url call like 'http://test.com/test.php' to the variable json3 at line 6. 
The output of the url call looks like 
    { "inp1:val1": { "data": [ [ 1378267200000, 0.0743 ], [ 1378270800000, 0.1787 ] ] }}

Currently I have this hard coded like this 
    var json3 = { "inp1:val1": { "data": [ [ 1378267200000, 0.0743 ], [ 1378270800000, 0.1787 ] ] }}

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <title>JSON to CSV</title>
    <script src="json.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var json3 = { "inp1:val1": { "data": [ [ 1378267200000, 0.0743 ], [ 1378270800000, 0.1787 ] ] }}
    DownloadJSON2CSV(json3["inp1:val1"].data);

    function DownloadJSON2CSV(objArray)
    {
        var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;

        var str = '';

        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            var line = '';

            for (var index in array[i]) {
                line += array[i][index] + ',';
            }

            line.slice(0,line.Length-1); 

            str += line + '\r\n';
        }
        window.open( "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + escape(str))
    }

    </script>

   </head>
   <body>
    <h1>This page downloads csv....</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is the server the data is coming from in your domain? If it's not you'll need to use JSONP and the server needs to serve JSONP data. That's the only way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can give this try,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var xmlhttp;
var txt,x,i,json3;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  // code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    json3 = eval(xmlhttp.responseText);
    DownloadJSON2CSV(json3["inp1:val1"].data);
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://test.com/test.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

function DownloadJSON2CSV(objArray)
{
    var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;

    var str = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var line = '';

        for (var index in array[i]) {
            line += array[i][index] + ',';
        }

        line.slice(0,line.Length-1); 

        str += line + '\r\n';
    }
    window.open( "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + escape(str))
}

</script>
```

Let me know.

Comment: Thanks SilverBlade. That didn't work.It does not go into                      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()

Answer (score 0):

I see this more as a design decision other than the method to have this fulfilled.

1. If the data is supposed to exist on the page *right when it is loaded*, and provided you have a dynamic back-end you're able to query (some back-end language that formats and return the page's HTML), it would be wise to have that variable populated immediately when the page is loaded.
2. If you need to really query for that data and something is supposed to be done with it when the page is loaded, force the ajax call when the page initializes by inserting the ajax call at the beginning of your HTML (after any libraries are loaded and when it makes sense to have a *script* tag. Initialize the variable (*json3*) that will be made available on the global context before the call is made.
3. If something is supposed to happen **after** the variable is assigned a value, adopt an asynchronous callback, that will be invoked when the ajax call is finished:

   ```
    function doAjaxCall(callback) {
        //your ajax call here

        //and within your ajax success/failure handler:
            callback(value);
    }

    //your callback function
    function myCallback(value) {
        //do something with value here, such as
        alert(value);
    }

    //and invoke it with
    doAjaxCall(myCallback);
   ```

The main point to my suggestions is to embrace the fact that you won't know when the variable is assigned a value unless you're able to cope with the asynchronous nature of the Ajax calls (exactly what the *A* stands for in Ajax).

It's also important to suggest the use of [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) (or any other library) to make your life easier if you're not already using any.

Comment: Thanks Leon. I am new to json/ajax/jquery. As you can see from my use case when the user pulls up this html page it downloads the csv from the variable json3. I am trying to do the same with the call to http://test.com/test.php which returns the same exact value as is hardcoded now to the variable json3. Can you tell me how do I do the the jquery/ajax call please? sample code will be helpful.